# Await / Async with a conditional statement and IIAEF

Tags: javascript, async-await

**Description**

I want to conditionally call a db `SELECT` within a non-async function. I wrapped it in a `IIAEF?` like so

```
async function getScopedDataPolicies() {
  const test = new Promise((res) => {
    console.log('2')
    res('test1')
  })

  return test;
}

function nonAsyncMethod() {
  (async () => {
    console.log('1')
    const test = getScopedDataPolicies();
    const policies = await test;
    console.log('3')
  })()

  console.log('4')
}

nonAsyncMethod()
```

My expectation is

```
1
2
3
4
```

But I get

```
1
2
4
3
```

What wouldn't the `await` work in the immediately invoking method??

Look at these examples; am I missing something?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function

Comment: await waits inside the IIFE ... the code outside the IIFE does not - by the way, the order I get is the (expected) 2,3,1 - not sure how you're getting 1,3,2 - you must be reading it wrong

Comment: I fixed the `console.logs` to better reflect what I'm meaning @JaromandaX

Comment: yes, now your actual output reflects the code in the question - the reason is the same as I gave in the first comment ... async/await inside an IIFE makes no effect on code after it - i.e. `console.log('4')` does NOT "wait" for `await test`

Comment: I know.. the question is why not? Why does the await... not actually await anything. If I run synchronous code it works...

Comment: it DOES await ... but that await is inside the IIFE, not outside it

Comment: Do you understand what I'm trying to do? Do you know a solution?

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

All `await` does is pause the execution of the current function, until an async task has finished, at which point execution will continue. It does *not* pause all of Javascript, that kind of behavior is synchronous programming, and Javascript is built to avoid it, because it makes for a really bad user experience if Javascript has to stall every time you make a rest request, etc.

**update**

Some possible workarounds:

1. await the IIFE, or take out the IIFE entirely. The IIFE is an async function, so it'll return a promise when it'scalled. You're not awaiting that promise, which is why your outer sync function continues on without waiting for it to finish.

```js
async function nonAsyncMethod() {
  await (async () => {
    console.log('1')
    const test = getScopedDataPolicies();
    const policies = await test;
    console.log('3')
  })()

  console.log('4')
}
```

2. Move `console.log('4')` into your IIFE. I know that `console.log('4')` might represent a whole log of code, but in some cases, you've just got to move it all inside - break up your function into smaller functions if you have to.

Comment: I still don't understand. The `getScopedDataPolicies` isn't finished executing and it's still within the `IIFE`?

Comment: Based on what I'm trying to do, do you have a solution?

Comment: @Phil I updated my answer to give you some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

await inside the IIFE doesn't effect the outer function

To do so, you could either do this:

```js
async function getScopedDataPolicies() {
  const test = new Promise((res) => {
    console.log('2')
    res('test1')
  })

  return test;
}

async function nonAsyncMethod() {
  await (async () => {
    console.log('1')
    const test = getScopedDataPolicies();
    const policies = await test;
    console.log('3')
  })()

  console.log('4')
}

nonAsyncMethod()
```

or this:

```js
async function getScopedDataPolicies() {
  const test = new Promise((res) => {
    console.log('2')
    res('test1')
  })

  return test;
}

function nonAsyncMethod() {
  (async () => {
    console.log('1')
    const test = getScopedDataPolicies();
    const policies = await test;
    console.log('3')
  })().then(() => {
    console.log('4')
  })
}

nonAsyncMethod()
```

Note: if you need to "wait" for `nonAsyncMethod` - you can only do `await nonAsyncMethod()`, or `nonAsyncMethod.then(() => { continue here })`